# App doesn't open when click on FCM notification(Sent from FCM panel)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Hi I am using FCM for push notification in my app.

libraries:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
```

When i am sending notification from FCM panel , it is not opening app on some devices (Oneplus 6t, 5t) in some cases.

It works when I am sending notification using postman (data payload)

Comment: have you added pending intent which will handle click of notification?

Comment: How can i add pending intent for notification sent from FCM panel panel(notification payload) ?

Comment: I have posted the answer you can see to it if it helps

Comment: have you managed to resolve this issue?

Comment: no @Jordan, have not found any solution yet

Comment: @Ashish Can you share your payload?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set pending intent to your notification i can see that your asking how to add pending intent to notification sent from fcm panel, you should handle notification in OnMessageRecived in FirebaseMessagingService as in the following link

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/4017aac2bdc591dc8b9702953702f09921a4e76d/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L47-L90

Comment: FYI OnMessageRecived is not called when sending notification from firebase panel(notification payload) and app is in background